# Help me find the name of a 1980's sci fi tv show

Tags: story-identification, tv, weapon

All I remember is that the good guys in the show had a primary weapon that they would fire if they had enough time to charge it and fire it (it is not Robotech).

I don't think it was an animated show.  The weapon was a cannon, it looked like a ball with a nipple - when it fired it recoiled.  A bit like the ion cannon in The Empire Strikes Back. Please help!

Comment: Is that all you can remember? Can you remember any other characteristics, e.g. number of protagonists, villain type, anything else?

Comment: sorry, I really can't.  Every now and again I get flashes of something like white chunky components joining together.

Comment: All right, thanks for trying.

Comment: Is it a ship-mounted weapon, a vehicle-mounted weapon, a handheld weapon?

Comment: definitely not hand held. I want to say ship mounted, though it could be land based.

Comment: when the weapon fired it was more of a long pulse laser than a continual stream laser, if that helps.

Comment: I don't think it was animated (like CGI) either

Comment: the more I think about it, it was ship mounted

Comment: when it fired it was a long pulse, not a short one like the ion cannon on Empire Strikes Back.

Answer (score 4):

It's a long shot, given the scarce information, but might you be thinking of the Victory class ship Excalibur from [Crusade](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Crusade), the truncated sequel to [Babylon 5](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Babylon_5)?

Here's a picture of The Excalibur firing the main weapon:

[image]

The weapon was only usable as a last resort as it drained all of the available power of the ship, leaving barely enough for life support and gravity; after firing the ship was dead in space for approximately one minute, during which time it could neither manoeuvre nor use sensors.

Comment: when the weapon fired it was more of a long pulse laser than a continual stream laser, if that helps.  I also I don't think it was animated.

Comment: Crusade was live action with CGI ships, though I understand why you might think it was animated based on that image alone. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Could this be Starfleet (otherwise known as X-Bomber)?

[image: xbomber]

It's a *long* time since I saw this, but I think several components had to join together to form the ship in the picture.

Comment: it is not this one, but thanks so much for trying.  this show looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Space Adventure Cobra?

[image]

Comment: unfortunately that is not it either, I really feel is was a mixture of stop motion and live action.